# Postgres array datatype in waterline being converted to text

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sails.js, waterline

I need to create an App. We are using PostgreSQL as the underlying DB. The reason we decided on Postgres was because we wanted a relational database due to various entities and their relationships (which did not seem ideal for NoSQL databases like Mongo since there will be multiple joins) and at the same time we wanted to leverage the advantage of array and JSON datatypes of Postgres which is not available in MySQL.

We are using SailsJS framework due to its simplicity, built in sockets.io API and my prior (though very limited) experience with this framework (with MongoDB as underlying DB). It uses waterline as the underlying ORM.

Model.query() is really an awesome feature which allows me to run native SQL queries.

**The problem** that I am facing is related to defining a model with array datatype of Postgres. By default, if I check in database, the column is changed to text datatype in DB. 
I need to manipulate array fields using postgre's build in array functions. But for that, I need to be able to create a table with the required type. I need to know how is that possible ?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `json` field type when defining your Waterline model, e.g.:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        name: 'string',
        my_array: 'json',
        ...etc...
    }

}
```

Then you can save array data directly into the model, e.g.:

```
User.create({name: 'bob', my_array: [1,2,3]}).exec(...);
```

and it will be translated to/from JSON by the underlying adapter.  In the case of `sails-postgresql`, it will use the `json` column type.

Comment: Thanks Scott.. I am getting an error when I send the packet via post request

`{
  "intColumn" : 1,
  "jsonColumn":  [1,2,3]
}`

Error message : 
`{
    "status": 500,
    "errors": [
        "invalid input syntax for type json"
    ]
}`

Comment: Not sure, works like a charm for me.  What version of Sails / sails-postgresql are you using?

Comment: Hi Scott, sorry for the late response. It worked on sails beta. But how do I access the keys of the json array ?
for example select my_array[0] does not work

Answer (score 0):

I don't have node.js running here, so it cannot test it right now. But try the following:

1. Use the array constructor syntax
2. Use proper enquoting

---

To 1)

```
 SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3+4];
```

---

To 2)

The [PostgreSQL documentation states](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/arrays.html):

> Remember that what you write in an SQL command will first be interpreted as a string literal, and then as an array. This doubles the number of backslashes you need. For example, to insert a text array value containing a backslash and a double quote, you'd need to write:

```
INSERT ... VALUES (E'{"\\\\","\\""}');
```

[Example fiddle with proper enquoting](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/06072/4).

Comment: Hi Stefan, I guess you misunderstood the question. The problem I am facing is not related to array datatype of Postgres but how waterline as an ORM handles them. I can work with array datatype comfortably but  waterline does not have this functionality. I am looking for a workaround

Comment: Ah, OK. Then I have to look into this later. I thought you had just the problem that queries you give to your ORM are not properly quoted.